# How to stop session from caching authenticated users data after logout

Tags: go

This code was leverage 
[here](https://gowebexamples.com/sessions/)

The code below was used to create users session in Go. The session is working fine.

The issue am having is that after 
user logout, if I click on browser back button. I can then still see the details of the logout user.

I have leverage stackoverflow solution here but no luck

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086688/golang-gorilla-sessions-cache-prevents-logout-functionality)

I have also added the following code to logout handler

```
w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, private, max-age=0")
w.Header().Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
w.Header().Set("X-Accel-Expires", "0")
```

here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
   "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var (
    // key must be 16, 24 or 32 bytes long (AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256)
    key = []byte("super-secret-key")
    store = sessions.NewCookieStore(key)
)

func secret(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "cookie-name")

    // Check if user is authenticated
    if auth, ok := session.Values["authenticated"].(bool); !ok || !auth {
        http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    // Print secret message
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "The cake is a lie!")
        fmt.Fprintln(w, session.Values["foo"])
}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "cookie-name")

    // Authentication goes here

    // Set user as authenticated
  session.Values["authenticated"] = true
  session.Values["foo"] = "bar"
  session.Values[42] = 43
    session.Save(r, w)

fmt.Fprintln(w, session.Values["authenticated"])
fmt.Fprintln(w, session.Values["foo"])
fmt.Fprintln(w, session.Values["2"])
}

func logout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "cookie-name")

    // Revoke users authentication
    session.Values["authenticated"] = false
        session.Values["foo"] = ""
        session.Values[42] = ""
    session.Save(r, w)

// prevent caching
w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, private, max-age=0")
w.Header().Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
w.Header().Set("X-Accel-Expires", "0")


}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/secret", secret)
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    http.HandleFunc("/logout", logout)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: you can trace the behavior with browser tool, like f12 or ctrl+shift+I

Comment: Delete the session cookie in logout, e.g. w.Header.Set("Set-Cookie", "cookie-name=; Max-Age=-1"). Make sure to use the appropriate paths and domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no way to "fix" your code without using JavaScript and changing the "secret" page before leaving it.

The problem is not in Go, or in `gorilla/sessions`, or even in HTTP: it is in the way the web browsers perform caching: at least in Firefox and Chrome, when going "back" and "forward" the browsers just display the cached page from disk, ignoring completely the headers.

Oh, and BTW: to try to force the browsers to stop caching a page, you should add those lines to the "secret" handler, and not to the "logout" one.